# Where do I store services in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I'm building an app in Symfony2 that receives a HTML string via an API, does some work on it (think of something like the Tidy library, only with a different purpose) and then returns the fixed HTML.

The stuff that does all the work is mostly written in services, because they don't need to return a Response object.

Where do I store those services? I'm putting them in bundles, but there's no obvious place to store them. I understand that they can be stored anywhere, but I'm wondering what the default convention is.

Comment: There really is no convention for services.  You should follow these general bundle guidelines: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html and maybe look at some of the other third party bundles for organizational ideas.

Comment: @Cerad ah fantastic link thank you. I wish the Symfony site was better organised so you could find these things.

Comment: Indeed, based on examples and community response, I've always used `Vendor\Bundle\Service\FooBarService.php`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If that code doesn't have to be re-usable outside of Symfony2 projects, you can just put it into your bundle.

I'd go for something like:

```
Acme\HtmlCleanerBundle\Cleaner\SimpleCleaner.php
```

Since it is a bundle, you can extract it to a separate package and re-use it for other Symfony2 projects.

If you want the code to be completely re-usable and standalone, I'd suggest you extract it to a separate library. You can still have dependencies on individual components (shameless plug: you could manage those dependencies through [composer](http://getcomposer.org/), which will be used by Symfony 2.1).

If you decide to go down that path, the bundle simply integrates the library into Symfony2 by providing DI container configuration for it.